# Baseline result is much better than state-of-the-art model

Tags: research-process

I am researching about Deep Learning based Intrusion Detection System. I found a paper on a well-known journal, which is considered as a state-of-the-art method in this research area, because it got many citations. In the paper, they proposed using Inception Resnet v4 to solve the problem and got the lowest error rate, compared to other studies.

I am developing a new method using their data pre-processing idea. First, I built a baseline, which is a very simple and shallow CNN. However, it produces a very good result, which is much better than the study using Inception Resnet (approximately 1-2%).

**Note that:** we are using the same dataset as well as data preprocessing as they described in the paper.

In addition, I am worry about that there maybe some mistakes while preprocessing data. Therefore, I re-implemented their proposed network and run it. The re-implemented results is not much different to the reported results in paper. So I think, my preprocessing step is correct.

The paper did not compare their results with a simple CNN model. They just compared with other architectures like LSTM, ANN, and basic machine learning models.

I am quite confused now. What should I do now?

Comment: You should discuss with your advisor. I don't work in machine learning but my first question would be if you are looking at training error or test error.

Comment: I don't work in machine learning either, but my first guess would be did you overfit the data? For example did you split the data into a training set, a cross validation set, and a test set?

Comment: It sounds like OP is using the same data split as the original paper. In this case, I would recommend implementing one or more of the “basic ML models” from the paper and verifying that you can reproduce those numbers as well. It would be surprising if you got their number for, say, a random forest, but a much better number for a shallow NN. (But this seems like a case where content answers will be more helpful than process answers; consider moving to [datascience.SE]).

Comment: What should I do now? **Publish**.

Comment: Thanks all. I checked the training and validation error. There is no sign of overfitting, I think. Because the graphs of training loss and validation loss all decrease beautifully. I think, it is suitable to ask on Data Science as @cag51 suggested.

Comment: Ok, I see you have posted it there, so I will close this one. I also reiterate my advice above; that’s definitely what I would do next in your situation (though asking your advisor is the best move, if you have one). Good luck